# AMP get dimensions

Tags: amp-html

How to get dimensions with AMP?

In react I can use ref.current.offsetWidth and Heigth, but I don't find a way to get it with AMP. I also tried to use getElementById but every time it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using `document.querySelector()` to grab your DOM element.
Pretty sure a lot of React APIs not gonna work with AMP